# CloudSQL persitent connections error

Tags: pdo, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud SQL 2nd generations instances and persistent connections using PHP PDO driver but, from time to time, and just in some App Engine instances, the pooled connections get corrupted and the connections begin to fail, sending an ugly message to the user.

I tried to solve this trying to make new connnections, even disabling persistency, but it didn't work:

```
for ($attempt = 1; !$this->link; $attempt++) {
                try {
                    if ($attempt > $persistent / 2) {
                        unset($options[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT]);
                    }
                    $this->link = new PDO($dsn_string, $user, $pass, $options);
                } catch (PDOException $err) {
                    if ($attempt <= $persistent) {
                        usleep($attempt * 100000);                           
                    } else {
                        throw new DB_Exception("Error connecting database (after $attempt attempts):\n" . $err->getMessage(), $err->getCode(), null, $err);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just get rid of persistent connections at all.

Comment: If I do that, the connection time to the Cloud SQL instance increases from a 2ms average to 60ms (https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=137&thanks=137&ts=1462191679)

Comment: Dropping persistent connection for one instance won't help, as the pool is already full. Any chance you can increase the number of `max_user_connections` in mysql? what is it now by the way?

Comment: `max_user_connections` is about 2000 connections, but this limit is not reached, because this error also happens when the database is mostly iddle

Comment: Ok, let's start from beginning then. What is that ugly error message sent to the user and what is the actual error message from PDO when connection fails?

Comment: When I said an ugly error message it was a way of speaking. This is the Exception I catch: Error connecting database (after 6 attempts):
                  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Unable to open connection to the Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: I see you are pushing on with this issue on the bug tracker. If you get this problem fixed, please post here the solution.